# DestroyWindow in OnDestroy not working

Tags: c++, mfc

Hi I'm making a dialog based application in MFC using:

```
BOOL CClockMasterDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

m_ModeTabs.Create(this,WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0);
}
```

If I destroy `m_ModeTabs` in `CClockMasterDlg::OnInitDialog` function after it is created using :

```
m_ModeTabs.DestroyWindow();
```

I get no memory but leaks when I place it in `CClockMasterDlg::OnDestroy()` I get memory leaks, even tough it gets called and returns `true`.
I don't believe that `OnDestroy` is `OnInitDialog`'s contrary, but then which function is? There is no `OnExitDialog`.

Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{601} client block at `0x00AEED48`, subtype c0, 212 bytes long.
a `CMFCVisualManager` object at `$00AEED48`, 212 bytes long
Object dump complete.
The program `[5312] ClockMaster.exe: Native` has exited with code 2 (0x2).

Even tough the window should be destroyed automatically since it`s not a pointer I still shouldn't get memory leaks should I? And since placing

```
m_ModeTabs.DestroyWindow();
```

in the `OnInitDialog` function after its created solves the memory leak it cant really be something else causing the trouble can it? Removing the `m_ModeTabs.Create(...` Also solves the memory leak so I'm quite certain that its `m_ModeTabs` causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I where actually hitting a bug which is gonna be "fixed in MFC for the next major release of Visual Studio".

The memory leak occurs when using a CVSListBox in a dialog only mfc application.

Information on the bug and several workarounds can be found here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/646445/cvslistbox-produces-memory-leaks

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/565327/memory-leaks-using-c

And another report on the bug here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/8870974f-1414-4dd7-b7c3-a1c320c0e91e

Quotation from first link:

> Hello,
>
> Thanks for the report. This issue has been fixed in MFC for the next
>   major release of Visual Studio.
>
> Pat Brenner Visual C++ Libraries Development

Answer (score 1):

Thought you don't say, I'm assuming that m_ModeTabs is a child window of your CClockMasterDlg.  In that case, or similar cases, you don't have to explicitly call DestroyWindow. When a window is Destroy()ed by Win32, all of its child windows are destroyed as well.

Since you declared your m_ModeTabs as a regular variable (not a pointer), the memory owned by it will be freed automatically by the C++ runtime during the destructor of CClockMasterDlg.

Comment: But then why am i getting a memory leak when I'm not manually destroying the window?

Comment: Find out where the CMFCViaualManager object is being allocated. Put a breakpoint in the constructor of it--assuming it has one. Start from there.